# How to check Microphone Volume in Angular

Tags: angular, webrtc, microphone

I wanted to check microphone volume in my Angular, are there any plugins or libraries which I can use?

```
let mic = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
mic.then(function () {
  alert('Mic Is Connected');
}).catch(function () {
  alert('Mic Is Not Connected');
});
```

I am testing if my Microphone is connected or not by above code, now I want a real time volume meter here

Comment: Here is a full example of a connected micro with volumne control:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GainNode/gain

Comment: @enno.void Thanks for the suggestion, I tried the code I get one error, Property 'webkitAudioContext' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis' and also it says onclick does not exist on type element

Comment: Which browser and version do you use? You can try directly without webkit prefix.

Comment: @Selçuk I am using chrome and I am writting this code into typescript file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a package avaliable in angular named **'decibal-meter'**, which will give you the decibels captured on your microphone.

**First of all Install decibal meter in your angular project,**

```
npm install --save decibel-meter
```

**After Installation import decibal meter in your component.ts file,**

```
import DecibelMeter from 'decibel-meter'
```

**Use the below code which will give you the result for your microphone volume**

```
decibals = 0;
const meter = new DecibelMeter('mictest');

meter.sources.then(sources => {
  meter.connect(sources[0]);
  meter.listenTo(0, (dB, percent) => this.decibals = Number(`${dB}`) + 100);

});
```

By this code you will get the decibals value and those values you can store it in a variable and you can access that variable in your HTML file.

**For displaying those decibels value you can use a progress bar which will look like sound/volume meter**

You can also refer to the official documentation for the **decibel-meter**,
[decibel-meter - NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/decibel-meter)

Comment: okay this worked and definitely an option can be used, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your need is not Angular specific, to note.

```
audioEl.addEventListener('volumechange', (event) => {
  console.log('The volume changed.');
  // here you can use the volumechange event or the volume attribute of the element.
});
```

You need to get the tracks inside the stream. Then get the current settings of these tracks. Then you will need to get the volume from each setings. Although the volume property of settngs looks like obsolete in MDN documentation, I have not been able to find another way.

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
  .then(function (stream) {
    alert('Mic Is Connected');
    const tracks = stream.getTracks();
    const settings = tracks.map(track => track.getSettings());
    const volumes = settings.map(setting => setting.volume);
    console.log("volumes: ", volumes);
}).catch(function () {
  alert('Mic Is Not Connected');
});
```

Also you can add this stream as srcObject to an audio element and then get the volume attribute. [Docs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#concept-media-volume)

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
    .then(function (stream) {
      alert('Mic Is Connected');
      const audioEl = document.createElement('audio');
      audioEl.srcObject = stream;
      const volume = audioEl.getAttribute('volume');
      console.log("volume: ", volume);
    }).catch(function () {
      alert('Mic Is Not Connected');
    });
```

And there might be a Web Audio API specific audio context way too.

Comment: volume value is returning null, and I want to make like volume/sound meter which continuously gives me volume from microphone

Comment: Then yu can use the `volumechange` event of the html audio element.